# XmlPullParser Exception

Tags: android, service, ksoap

I'm not able to resolve this error:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG @1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43e524c8)

I have an Android app which accesses a .NET web service. It passes an int and receives an int as a response. I'm using ksoap2.
I added the permissions to the manifest file also and moreover I included all jar files. However, I'm stuck and I am unable to view which SOAP request I am sending.

My code is:

```
public class FirstAppUI extends Activity{

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String URL = 
        "http://nautilussoft.biz.whbus12.onlyfordemo.com/staging/litigation/demowebservice.asmx";

private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/GetNumber";

private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetNumber";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("maxbelow", "123");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

        envelope.dotNet= true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "received object", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             Object resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            //SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "received object", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tv.setText("Received :" + resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("APP", "MalformedURLException while sending\n" + e.getMessage());
            tv.setText("Malformedexception"+e);
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            tv.setText("exception"+e1);

        }

        }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Give permission to your webserivce folder in IIS or through IIS manager.

Answer (score 0):

please check the weburl you are using.. its case sensitive... even though its working fine in a web browser, you should use the exact name in your code...